# Miktex 2.9 for windows 10

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I want to download miktex 2.9 for windows 10. Can you kindly help me with the same?

Kindly note: Please do not confuse with miktex 2.9 console. I do not want to install console version.

Thanks.

Comment: if you install miktex you will also get miktex console, that is a part of it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: After compl=ile, the error comes as lastpage.sty not found. I cannot resolve this problem. Can you kindly help? Thanks.

Comment: install the lastpage package with the miktex console.

Comment: How? Can you kindly help?

Comment: Launch `MiKTeX Package Manager` (in MiKTeX console, select `Packages` on the left).

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But it shows an error like: A connection to ftp.funet.fi could not be established.

More info: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-couldnt-connect

Comment: I recall two problems with installing MikTeX:  First, you have to completely delete the folder before reinstalling.  Second, use "automatic" rather than "ask" to install missing packages (editor dependent).